# Unable to bind class variable in model to HTML.DROPDOWNLISTFOR<>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

What i have is a business objct entity class variable declared in a  model , but when i try to bind the members of the class variable to a html.dropdownlistfor it doesnt work :

So here is my model:

```
public class pc
{
    public pcp  pk{get;set;}
    public int zip{get;set;}
    List<Suf> SufList{get;set;} //**
}
```

here pk is a  variable of business object pcp

```
public class pcp :basec
{
    [Key]
    public int pcid;
}

public class basec
{
    // **public string suf**
}
```

Now in my view , i call bind the above model to a dropdown:
 m is the model i.e. class pc

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.pk.suf, new selectlist(m => m.SufList, 
    "Key", "Value", m.pk.suf)
```

It gives an exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` 
at this drop down.

However at the same time if i declare the suf variable directly in m and use the binding like below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.suf, new selectlist(m => m.SufList, 
    "Key", "Value", m.suf)
```

It works, but this is not the desired way as you can easily see.

Any advice on what I need to be doing here, to set it right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that your property `pk` is null, but you are trying to access a property on it (`suf`). Make sure that your property `pk` has a value (set it on the model from your controller before passing the model to the view) and the error should go away.

Example controller action that renders your view:

```
public ViewResult YourAction() {
    pcp model = new pcp {
        pk = new pk(),
        SufList = new SufList {
            // Set list items here
        }
        // set other properties as needed
    };
    return View("YourViewName", model);
}
```

Also, I would highly recommend using more descriptive class and property names (rather than abbreviations) and consistent naming conventions. Typically, C# usage is CamelCase class/property names with the first letter capitalized.